# Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission"

Tags: c#, asp.net, localhost

I am facing a problem for running my website.

I have developed the website and when i hit F5 to view the results i am presented with this error

**Description**: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

**Exception Details**: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

[image: Error Page]

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Grant the FullTrust right to the remote share.

Comment: whats the share. can you please give an example

Comment: Sharename is the name of the folder you are trying to connect.

Comment: I am hitting F5 from my vs2008 to run the website in localhost. so my sharename is the name of folder in which my website code is. Right?

Answer (score 19):

This error usually happens if you Map your application folder on Network Drive or open Solution file from UNC Path. somthing like this:

> Invalid Example:  **\\my-server\my-project**

Try to open your solution from direct path

> Valid Example: **C:\Project\MyProject**

You can also make change to your privilege of **App Pool Identity** but it's not recommanded:

> Web Server (IIS) > App Pool Identity > Advance Settings > Set Identity as  **Network Service**

Comment: +1 From what I've found this is fairly undocumented around the web but has caught me out twice now. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Here is an official Microsoft support article confirming this issue, along with suggested fixes: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320268

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, must be marked as the answer. In my environment admin rights are not permited.

Comment: for Go daddy i just made **make change in web.config** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28841495/2218697)

Comment: But, what happen if I have all solution files in a network drive pointing to a TFS?

Answer (score 10):

the one shot solution worked for me was to set the App Pool **Identity**(Advance Settings) to **Network Service**

Answer (score 6):

Try to set "Load User Profile" value of your application pool to "True".
It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth, I found that the `AjaxControlKit.dll` on the deployed server was blocked. To resolve this, I copied over the dll to a new folder then copied and pasted in the `bin` folder. I guess .net doesn't like a dll being copied over directly to the web folder

Comment: FYI, I had this problem twice.  The first time, the 32-bit solution from @Shrink was the answer.  This time, it was AjaxControlToolkit.dll needed to be unblocked.   Just goes to show any one of these answers could be valid.

Answer (score 3):

you can run the following command to Grant FullTrust to remote share:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url
>   "file:////\yourcomputername\yoursharename*" FullTrust -exclusive on

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. btw. don't forget to restart your application pool after running this command

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well but have not seen this particular solution mentioned anywhere.

After checking permissions for the IIS user, the user for Impersonation, and granting Full Trust to the application, and still getting the error, I installed Procmon.exe on the server running IIS and noticed that IIS was attempting to access some Framework64 files for the offending website. I inspected the application pool advanced settings and discovered that "enable 32-bit applications" was set to false. Changing this setting to true proved to be the correct action. Life is good.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the solutions posted here and a number of other places and nothing worked for me. I had my project located on a network drive which worked until I tried to use the AjaxControlToolkit 2.0 in my project. Apparently, something about permissions on the network drive would not allow the controls in the toolkit to run. I moved my project back to my local hard drive and it all started working.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem, then I realised that I was running the solution from a remote folder. Copy the necessary file to the local folder will solve the issue. But make sure that your folder have the full permission

Answer (score 0):

While all of the other answers on this page *may* be the cause of anyone's problem, the most common one is due to OS security changes in Windows Server 2012 and above.  Any file downloaded from the internet is flagged as suspicious by Windows and needs to be manually unblocked before using it in IIS.  So if you FTP your code, email it, or transfer it through a cloud provider, it will be flagged and blocked.

The best solution is to use the web publishing facilities built in to Visual Studio or transfer through a network share if you're on a domain, each of which avoid this problem.  However, if you must copy your code to another server by one of the means I described above, you should zip everything prior to transfer so you are only left with a single file to unblock.  If you unzip before you unblock, then each file will be blocked and multi-selection will not give you the option to unblock.

So finally... to unblock: Right click the file and select Properties.  Right there on the first page near the bottom you'll see an Unblock button along with the warning that the file was downloaded from the internet!

Answer (score 0):

If the dll is compiled using this option (Do not merge. Create a separate assembly for each page and control), please make sure the dll is up to date. I faced the error due to aspx file is new one, but dll still using old one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution that worked on my system and did not require changing to `Network Service`.

Go to Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Load User Profile: True

[Source of this answer](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/822179/Request-for-the-Permission-of-Type-System-Web).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to resolve this issue is Run the Visual Studio as "Administator". Right click on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as Administrator".

Once you open Visual Studio with Full admin rights, you will be able access the page without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this error and it seems to be a generic error. As there are several answers to this issue, I am going to add mine. Republishing the website on the remote server seems to fix it for me.